# Mysql order by is very slow from 1,000,000 rows, we have nearly 300,000 search results

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-order-by, filesort

When we do Natural Search in Mysql from 1,000,000 rows, we have nearly 300,000 search results.
This query lasts 7-8 seconds when we want to select the first 2,000 documents with the highest natural score.

This time is too long for us. How can we shorten the duration of the first 2,000 pick by sort by natural rating?

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
select (match(baslik,detay) against('+borçlu +yetkili +icra +dairesi +tercih +kayyım +borç +daire +borc' in natural LANGUAGE mode)) as n from ictihat 
 where   (match(baslik,detay) against('+borçlu +yetkili +icra +dairesi +tercih +kayyım +borç +daire +borc +Deyn +Vecibe +Evam +Liability +Kredi +Ödev +Ödünç +Namus +borcu +Takanak +Medyun +Debitor +Zimemdar +Yükümlü +Verecekli +Bölük +Çember +Çevre +İdare +Menzil +Ofis +Temşiyet +Yürütme +Curator +Kayyum +Yeğleme +Salahiyettar +Salâhiyyetdâr +Salahiyetli +Mezun' in natural LANGUAGE mode))
 **order by n desc** LIMIT 0,2000
```

**Result: 4.703 sec**

Explain:

```
1 SIMPLE ictihat fulltext aramafull aramafull 0 const 1 100.00 Using where; Using filesort
```

---

```
 select (match(baslik,detay) against('+borçlu +yetkili +icra +dairesi +tercih +kayyım +borç +daire +borc' in natural LANGUAGE mode)) as n from ictihat 
 where   (match(baslik,detay) against('+borçlu +yetkili +icra +dairesi +tercih +kayyım +borç +daire +borc +Deyn +Vecibe +Evam +Liability +Kredi +Ödev +Ödünç +Namus +borcu +Takanak +Medyun +Debitor +Zimemdar +Yükümlü +Verecekli +Bölük +Çember +Çevre +İdare +Menzil +Ofis +Temşiyet +Yürütme +Curator +Kayyum +Yeğleme +Salahiyettar +Salâhiyyetdâr +Salahiyetli +Mezun' in natural LANGUAGE mode))
 LIMIT 0,2000
```

**Result: 1.005 sec**

Explain:
1   SIMPLE  ictihat     fulltext    aramafull   aramafull   0   const   1   100.00  Using where

Comment: Your table has fulltext index?

Comment: 30% of the rows contain all of those words?  What will you do with 2000 results?  Most _humans_ stop after less than 20.

Comment: Yes. Our table have fulltext index

Comment: We will improve and re-rank the result from natural search and we'll show 200 pages with 10 documents